# pa11y failed to Error: Failed to launch chrome

Tags: pa11y

Getting below error while running `"pa11y www.google.com"`

> Welcome to Pa11y

Running Pa11y on URL `www.google.com`

> Error: Failed to launch chrome!
>   [1127/090329.278232:FATAL:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(116)] No usable
>   sandbox! Update your kernel or see
>   chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/linux_suid_sandbox_development.md
>   for more information on developing with the SUID sandbox. If you want
>   to live dangerously and need an immediate workaround, you can try
>   using --no-sandbox.

Comment: npm -v
6.12.1
node -v
v12.13.1
pa11y -V
5.3.0
RHEL vrsion
7.6 (Maipo)
Also, I tried the below-mentioned steps, but no luck.
https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md

Comment: Please edit your post, rather than adding updates in the comments. 
Also, please format your post correctly, so the error message is easily readable.

Comment: Was this resolved by any chance - i ran into the same issue today and am chasing the wild goose


Any suggestions or workaround on this - please comment